# What can we say about two graphs if they have similar adjacency matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, similar-matrices

Suppose we have two (finite, simple, undirected) graphs, what can we say about these graphs if they have [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) [adjacency matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)?

Observations to begin with:

- If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, then they have similar adjacency matrices, $A_1$ and $A_2$.  In fact, they are similar in an even stronger sense: they satisfy $A_1=PA_2P^{-1}$, where $P$ is a permutation matrix.
- The following non-isomorphic graphs, have similar adjacency matrices:

  [image: K(1,4)] $\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image: C(4) union K(1)]
- Similarity of adjacency matrices is an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) on the set of $n$-vertex graphs.
- Graphs with similar adjacency matrices must be [isospectral graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory#Isospectral_graphs).

Comment: Given two such graphs you can say that they have the same number of edges and triangles.

Comment: Also if your graphs are regular then they have the same number of spanning trees as well.